# Collect values in cells into a list, then hold in a new dataframe using Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
| id   | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
|------|------|------|------|------|
| 1    | A    | B    | C    | 0    |
| 4    | X    | 0    | Y    | 0    |
```

I am trying to collect all the values in the rows into a list, and then put them into a new dataframe, like such:

```
| id | output    |
|----|-----------|
| 1  | [A, B, C] |
| 4  | [X, Y]    |
```

I was trying to use an apply function to do this, but I can't seem to ignore the (string) `'0'` values.

Here's the data:

```
df = [    {'id' : 1, 'col1' : 'A', 'col2': 'B', 'col3':   'C', 'col4':'0'},
          {'id' : 4, 'col1' : 'X', 'col2':  '0', 'col3':  'Y', 'col4':'0'}
          ]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']]
df
```

Comment: Like your previous question, I'm assuming that `id` is your index variable again?

Comment: Yes it is the index!

Comment: in a broader sense, what are you actually trying to accomplish? in other words, why do you think you need to do this? generally speaking, storing collection of any sort in a dataframe is something you don't want to do.

Comment: Totally agree, Paul. I'm actually creating a table to ultimately export into a CSV so a human can read the values.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have commas in the text:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[x!='0']), axis=1).str.split(',')
Out: 
id
1    [A, B, C]
4       [X, Y]
dtype: object
```

If you want a DataFrame:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[x!='0']), axis=1).str.split(',').to_frame('output')
Out: 
       output
id           
1   [A, B, C]
4      [X, Y]
```

Or

```
df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[x!='0']), axis=1).str.split(',').to_frame('output').reset_index()
Out: 
   id     output
0   1  [A, B, C]
1   4     [X, Y]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in `map` function to convert the row from a list of values into a string:

```
df = [{'id' : 1, 'col1' : 'A', 'col2': 'B', 'col3':   'C', 'col4':'0'},
      {'id' : 4, 'col1' : 'X', 'col2':  '0', 'col3':  'Y', 'col4':'0'}
      ]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df['output'] = map(str, df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']].values)
df.drop(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

This will give you:

```
|   | id | output            |
|----------------------------|
| 0 | 1  | ['A' 'B' 'C' '0'] |
| 1 | 4  | ['X' '0' 'Y' '0'] |
```

Edit: If you want only characters you can use:

```
f = lambda x: str([y for y in x if y.isalpha()])
df['output'] = map(f, df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']].values)
```

Comment: I like this a lot... But I really don't want the '0' values!

Comment: But those annoying zeros are actually characters too 